# How can I create a named section in an NSPopUpButton

Tags: cocoa, appkit

I'd like to duplicate the appearance of the menu below, with named "sections" in the pop-up button's menu.

[image: NSPopUpButton with named sections]

I can tell that the grey horizontal lines are `NSMenuItem.separator()` but setting the title and attributed title on those doesn't work. Adding submenus gets me nowhere, as does adding disabled menu items. This seems to be a common pattern, and I find it hard to believe that it's just ad-hoc with attributed strings / custom views everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a `NSMenuItem.separator()` plus a disabled NSMenuItem to display the title. With `NSMenuItem` `attributedTitle` and `indentationLevel` you can customise  the appearance of the text. Consider that `NSMenu` autoenablesItems can also have an effect.

Best, Marc

Comment: This is true, but it turns out that Apple internally uses a menu item with a custom view, `FILocationPopUpSectionView`. Unfortunately I can't get at the subviews or constraints so can't comment on how it's laid out, fonts, colors, etc. but I don't think it's possible to achieve the same appearance using purely the attributed title and indentation, since you can't "outdent" your headers leftward.

Comment: "With NSMenuItem attributedTitle and indentationLevel you can customise the appearance of the text." Partially, but can you do a _negative_ indentation (which would more closely mimic Apple's look)?

Comment: The label text of a disabled menu item looks like light grey, while the labels of Apple Menu are dark grey. If you turn the menu item on, the label text gets your custom text color but the menu item gets enabled, so the user can select it, while he shouldn't. The only way I found is to create a menu item custom view containing my custom label. And if you have several labels it's a mess.

Comment: And if you use [NSMenuItem sectionHeaderWithTitle:@"Header"]; the label text shows up with a light dark color, even if you setAttributedTitle: with a blackColor.

Answer (score 0):

If you run on macOS 14.0 or higher you could add a section header with

```
NSMenuItem *header = [NSMenuItem sectionHeaderWithTitle:@"Sections"];
```